# How to edit a header in a fasta sequence by cutting some parts of it and keeping the main text of the sequence using a linux command line?

Tags: linux, fasta

I have a multi fasta file named fasta1.fasta that contains the sequences and their IDs. What i want is to cut the header of the sequence that have the ID and reduce it to contains the ID accession number of the sequence only. I used the command line `grep '>' fasta1.fasta | cut -d " " -f 1` to cut the parts that i want from the header but the output that i get is the IDs accession numbers only without the rest of the sequences. My sequences looks like this:

```
>tr|Q8IBQ5|Q8IBQ5_PLAF7 40S ribosomal protein S10, putative OS=Plasmodium falciparum (isolate 3D7) OX=36329 GN=PF3D7_$
MDKQTLPHHKYSYIPKQNKKLIYEYLFKEGVIVVEKDAKIPRHPHLNVPNLHIMMTLKSL
KSRNYVEEKYNWKHQYFILNNEGIEYLREFLHLPPSIFPATLSKKTVNRAPKMDEDISRD
VRQPMGRGRAFDRRPFE
>tr|Q8IEB1|Q8IEB1_PLAF7 TBC domain protein, putative OS=Plasmodium falciparum (isolate 3D7) OX=36329 GN=PF3D7_132020$
MEYKLEFLSYLLIFKKKNERISKFDEQIKTCINIFEKSIINESDLKYLFERNILDMNPGV
RSMCWKLALKHLSLDSNKWNTELIEKKKLYEEYIKSFVINPYYSCVDNKKKEFVKETEKE
PKGKNMKDEYIEYNLDRNKTYYHKDDSLLKLQNDNNTKQMDYLEDEKYSSMDDECSEDNW
```

The output that i get is:

```
>tr|Q8IBQ5|Q8IBQ5_PLAF7

>tr|Q8IEB1|Q8IEB1_PLAF7
```

While the output desired is:

```
>tr|Q8IBQ5|Q8IBQ5_PLAF7
MDKQTLPHHKYSYIPKQNKKLIYEYLFKEGVIVVEKDAKIPRHPHLNVPNLHIMMTLKSL
KSRNYVEEKYNWKHQYFILNNEGIEYLREFLHLPPSIFPATLSKKTVNRAPKMDEDISRD
VRQPMGRGRAFDRRPFE
>tr|Q8IEB1|Q8IEB1_PLAF7
EYKLEFLSYLLIFKKKNERISKFDEQIKTCINIFEKSIINESDLKYLFERNILDMNPGV
RSMCWKLALKHLSLDSNKWNTELIEKKKLYEEYIKSFVINPYYSCVDNKKKEFVKETEKE
PKGKNMKDEYIEYNLDRNKTYYHKDDSLLKLQNDNNTKQMDYLEDEKYSSMDDECSEDNW
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: i know but in my real files they are just 1 line.Only here they were 2 lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Variant 1:

  ```
  sed '/^>/s/ .*//'
  ```
- Variant 2:

  ```
  perl -pe 's/ .*// if /^>/'
  ```

That is, in all lines that start with `>`, remove everything after and including the first space.